# Formal terms for pronunciations of loanwords in source and recipient languages?

Tags: terminology, pronunciation, borrowing

If they exist, what are formal terms meaning "pronunciation of a loanword in the donor language" and "pronunciation of a loanword in the recipient language"? In shorter terms, the original pronunciation and the adopted pronunciation. The articles on imported words that I've found so far mention pronunciation of specific words rather than describing pronunciation in general.

Comment: The two languages are the source and target language, so I guess the pronunciations would be the source and target pronunciation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That would be a good answer!

Comment: @Draconis If they’re accepted terms – I didn’t look anything up, was just throwing it out there that it would be a logical thing to call them. I don’t actually know if there is an established term.